# Block a BotNet with htaccess by Referrer, Agent, or Page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We have been getting slammed by a BotNet.

I put in two rules that cut down 80% of the traffic, but these requests are still coming through.

```
172.69.34.192 - - [21/Nov/2019:06:03:12 -0600] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 453750 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
172.69.34.192 - - [21/Nov/2019:06:03:15 -0600] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 452909 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
```

This BotNet changes +3,000 different IP addresses a day but always does a Post and then a Get. The traffic is direct and there is no page referrer.

How can I block these in my htaccess using a combination of post and get to wp-login.php and there is no page: "-"?

So far I have these in place to block the 80% of other undesired bots.

```
# Stop Bots with Bogus User Agents
SetEnvIf User-Agent "^-$" bad_user
SetEnvIf User-Agent "^$" bad_user
<Files ~ "^(wp-login|xmlrpc)\.php">
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Deny from env=bad_user
</Files>

# Block Specific Bots by Name
SetEnvIfNoCase User-agent (yandex|baidu|mj12bot|ahrefsbot|blexbot|dotbot|exabot|seznambot|aihitbot|spbot|mj12bot|obot|deusu|ia_archiver|metauri|flipboardproxy|flicky|pycurl|casper|cmsworldmap|diavol|purebot|comodo|feedfinder|planetwork) not-allowed
<Limit GET POST PUT>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=not-allowed
</Limit>
```

What I am looking for is something that blocks a referrer of "-". Maybe something like this, but I am not sure if this is the correct syntax or if I can combine it with the above #Stop Bots entry.

```
SetEnvIf Referrer "^-$" bad_bot
<Files ~ "^(wp-login|xmlrpc)\.php">
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Deny from env=bad_bot
</Files>
```

Comment: Invest instead in Cloudflare or any other product that protects sites for a living.

Comment: Not an option at the moment, but we have looked at it. I'm certain there has to be a way to craft a rule that can take care of these last big problems.

Comment: You can not handle two separate requests (a POST, followed by a GET) in .htaccess at the same time - each of those requests is independent, rewriting happens for each one individually.

Comment: Understood. But I could add a rule, if it is the the wp-login page, and the page referrer is "-" then block. I just don't know the syntax for that or if I should use rewrite conditions, SetEnvIf, or another php module.

Comment: How about moving `wp-login.php` to a different URL which only you know (and you don't publish), and then just blocking anything which tries to hit the old, default location?

Comment: We did try something similar. We have a customer login, so the link is exposed on the UI. The bot scanned the site and updated the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I could add a rule, if it is the the `wp-login` page, and the page referrer is `"-"` then block. I just don't know the syntax for that

You may try this rule as your **topmost** rule (just below `RewriteBase` line):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /wp-login\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^-?$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This will return `403` (Forbidden) error for above two conditions.

Comment: I am not able to put it as the topmost rule because Wordpress controls the Rewrite module. I placed it after, and it is not working. What about the SetEnvIf? Can I set the Referrer to "-" or "^-$" and accomplish a similar effect?

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess in question then I can understand better.

Comment: Posted the full file. Bots are still getting through.

Comment: Can you change second line to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^-?$` and move this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: I cannot move it inside because Wordpress overwrites that whole #begin to #end section. I will try changing to %{HTTP_REFERER} ^-?$ without quotes.